# Optimise a minimum operation on a python list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of list where each list corresponds to the boundary point of a figure. I have to extract a list of four points, each defining the enclosing rectangle of the figures. For example, I have this list

```
[[[2,5],[3,4],[5,8],[5,6],[5,9]],
 [[11,14],[12,15],[16,17]],
 ...
]
```

Here each list defines a figure boundary. what I have to get is list of four points as

```
[[min_x, min_y], [min_x, max_y], [max_x, max_y], [max_x, min_y]]
```

i.e.

```
[[[2,4],[2,9],[5,9],[5,4]],
 [[11,14], [11, 17], [16,17], [16,14]]
 ...
]
```

I have done this using python loop which is perfectly working.
Here is the code.

```
cleaned_contours = list()
for cur_cont in contours:
    min_x, min_y = cur_cont.min(axis=0).flatten()
    max_x, max_y = cur_cont.max(axis=0).flatten()

    cleaned_contours.append(np.array([[min_x, min_y], [min_x, max_y], [max_x, max_y], [max_x, min_y]]))
```

Is there a way I can do this without using loops or list comprehension.
I am using python3.

Comment: But why do you want to avoid for loops?

Comment: That is the coding standard that we follow.

Comment: Wait, you have numpy arrays? Could you please show a complete example?

Comment: Avoiding loops? That's a necessity if you want to process things like lists or sets, unsure what kind of coding standard frowns upon them

Comment: I guess you could take a recursive approach, but...

Comment: If you're not using Numpy arrays in general, prohibiting comprehensions or generator expressions doesn't strike me as very wise, as they are often very readable, elegant und perform better than explicit loops. If on the other hand you're operating on Numpy arrays in the first place, you should point that out, so someone can provide an efficient Numpy-oriented answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension if you like (still a loop + ugly):

```
a = [[[2,5],[3,4],[5,8],[5,6],[5,9]], [[11,14],[12,15],[16,17]]]

[[[j[0], j[1]], [j[0], j[3]], [j[2], j[3]], [j[2], j[1]]] for j in [np.array(i).min(0).tolist() + np.array(i).max(0).tolist() for i in a]]

#[[[2, 4], [2, 9], [5, 9], [5, 4]],
# [[11, 14], [11, 17], [16, 17], [16, 14]]]
```