# Finding minimum value in list of lists

Tags: python, list, minimum

I want to find the smallest value in a list of lists in Python. Example:

```
ls = [[2,3,5],[8,1,10]]
```

The minimum value in `ls` is `1`. How can I get that in a simple way?

Comment: `min(elem for subls in ls for elem in subls)`

Comment: What did you try so far? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The proposed dupe ([Optimise a minimum operation on a python list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56668205/1782792)) had very little to do with this question.

Comment: @cs95 Ah sorry I didn't see that, sure do close it if you found a proper dupe (I couldn't find it myself). That's a more general case, but if it's good for you it is for me.

Comment: @jdehesa it isn't a perfect dupe, just a little more general. I'll go ahead and close it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# find the min of each sublist, then find the global min
min(map(min, ls))
# 1
```

---

```
# flatten `ls`, then find the min
min(y for x in ls for y in x)
# 1
```

---

```
# use itertools.chain to flatten `ls`
min(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ls))
# 1
```

---

```
ls = [[2, 3, 5], [8, 1, 10]] * 10000

%timeit min(y for x in ls for y in x)            # 7.31 ms ± 64.9 µs
%timeit min([min(l) for l in ls])                # 6.24 ms ± 56.9 µs
%timeit min(map(min, ls))                        # 5.44 ms ± 151 µs
%timeit min(min(ls, key=min))                    # 5.28 ms ± 129 µs
%timeit min(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ls))   # 2.67 ms ± 62.5 µs
```

Comment: There are dupes for it, but not for this exact question!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Seems like an attempt at a self QA, so I posted what I thought were decent alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
min_abs = min([min(l) for l in ls])
```

Comment: you can skip the `[` and `]`, and it avoid the temporary list.

Comment: Building a list of min values like this is a little more wasteful than it needs to be. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811402/4909087) for a timings comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this:

```
res = min(min(ls, key=min))
```